# shell Script is executed in steps

Tags: bash, shell

I have this problem. I wrote very simple script, to open 3 terminals with specific position and size and I want to run it after boot.

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh    

wmctrl -s 1 

gnome-terminal --geometry=90x45+960+0 
gnome-terminal --geometry=83x21+0+0 
gnome-terminal --geometry=83x20+0+500 

wmctrl -s 0
```

When I run this script in terminal, it works perfectly.

I tried to run it through "Startup Applications".
But when I rebooted PC, workspace was switched and opened 1st terminal and script stopped. When I closed terminal, then script continue with opening 2nd terminal and stop again. This is with all 3 terminals.

Same happens when I tried to do it via crontab.

I did

> 2> ~/test.txt

but no errors.

Why doesn't this script not run at once, but in steps?

Comment: ``2> ~/test.txt` from crontab: are you sure of the location of `~` ? I would put an absolute path instead...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre test file was created, but was empty, therefor I think that `~` is fine

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running each in the background?

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=90x45+960+0 &
gnome-terminal --geometry=83x21+0+0 &
gnome-terminal --geometry=83x20+0+500 &
```

Comment: it works, but same as Kirill's , last part `wmctrl -s 0` is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your script runs three `gnome-terminal` consequently, that's why the behavior you described (it's like `mkdir x; ls`: `ls` runs after `mkdir` finishes).

If you want to run `wmctrl -s 0` when *all* terminals finish, use this:

```
#!/bin/sh    

wmctrl -s 1 

pids=
for geom in 90x45+960+0 83x21+0+0 83x20+0+500; do
  # run gnome-terminal in background and save its process ID 
  gnome-terminal --geometry="$geom" &
  pids="$pids $!"
done
wait $pids

wmctrl -s 0
```

Comment: It works with termianls, but last command  `wmctrl -s 0` is not executed.